# Como preencher uma DIV com outra DIV adequadamente?

Tags: css

Eu possuo uma `<div>` para guardar alguns elementos, sendo que o último elemento será um outra `<div>`. Eu quero fazer com que este último elemento tenha altura o suficiente para preencher a `<div>` mãe, porém sem ultrapassar o limite.

Para realizar esta tarefa, tentei utilizar `height: 100%`. O problema é que isso faz com que a `<div>` filha tenha o tamanho total da `<div>` mãe.

```css
#parents{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

#parents > div {
    width: 100%;
}

#target {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parents">
    <div style="background: red;"> Uma divizinha aqui </div>   
    <div style="background: green;"> Mais uma outra divizinha ali</div>
    <div id="target" style="background: yellow;">Minha div alvo</div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer isso utilizando apenas CSS?

Comment: Affz, por que negativar a pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca o `container` mãe com `display: flex` e `flex-direction: column`, depois a  div que vc quer que preencha o total do container mãe vc coloca `flex: 1;`

```css
#parents{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#parents > div {
    width: 100%;
}

#target {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parents">
    <div style="background: red;"> Uma divizinha aqui </div>   
    <div style="background: green;"> Mais uma outra divizinha ali</div>
    <div style="background: pink;"> Pare e estude FLEX, Pare e estude FLEX, Pare e estude FLEX</div>
    <div id="target" style="background: yellow;">Minha div alvo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vlw hugo. Man eu não preciso estudar flex, eu preciso estudar CSS kkkk O conhecimento que tenho sobre CSS é muito pouco, porque eu não gosto muito de front-end e acho um saco código CSS.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 com Flex vc resolve 80% dos problemas de layout/css